# My texture paint isn't applying to my image texture correctly

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, image

I draw an "A" in as a texture paint, and for some reason a little A appears in the image over and over again I can't seem to get it to stop repeating. I tried changing the image texture node to "extended and clip" but it still does it. I believe the texture resolution is set to the default.

Has anyone else run into this issue? I would be very grateful for some help before I pull my hair out.

[image]

Comment: Hello it doesn't seem to repeat in your screenshot, but could you please pack your image and share your file? https://blendertribu.forumactif.com/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

so after sleeping on it, I figured it out, turns out that at some point, I gave it a texture of the image texture meaning that as I was painting on a texture, it was re-applying the image a second time as a texture.

The fix is to go into Active tool>Brush Settings>Texture / and remove the selected texture so that it goes back to the white and grey checkered box.